# NFS stalls on client side when server goes down

Tags: nfs

I'm running a few Amazon EC2 instances. One of them is a NFS server with the following exports:

```
/home/user/comm 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0(ro) 50.0.0.0/255.0.0.0(ro)
```

And in the client side:

```
xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/user/comm /home/user/user_comm nfs noauto,soft,intr 0 0
```

I've tried to:

- change *soft* to *hard*
- disable the noauto
- use the elastic ip address instead of the public dns

The issue I'm having is whenever the server reboots, the client isn't able to see it anymore. The server gets assigned the same elastic ip address though. In order for the client to be able to connect to the server again, I've to change the fstab to point to whatever resolution I wasn't using before. So, if I was using the IP address, I have to use the hostname this name, and vice-versa.

I'm new with the whole NFS client<>server on EC2, so if anyone can enlighten me with suggestions, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting NFS stale mounts due to server reboot.  The change in your fstab naming is causing the NFS dialog to restart and thus address the problem.  NFS cannot carry a service across server reboots as it must accomplish some security negotiation on establishment of the service that will not persist.

Comment: Well, it actually depends on what version of NFS you are using.  Use a sufficient old UDP protocol version of NFS and it will survive a server reboot (e.g. NFSv2).  Your security may suffer, though.

Comment: @Seth: Awesome, that solved my problem. Thanks a lot!